# Concatenate contents from stdout and from file

Tags: cat, stdout, output

How can we concatenate results from stdout (or stderr) and a file into a final file.

For example

```
ls -a | grep text1
```

concatenate with `file2.txt` into a final result (not `file2.txt`), without storing `grep text1` to something intermediate such as `grep text1 > file1.txt`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
ls -a | grep text1 | cat file2.txt -
```

The `-` stands for standard input. Alternatively you may write

```
ls -a | grep text1 | cat - file2.txt
```

to have the output in different order.

---

Yet another possibility using process substitution:

```
cat <(ls -a | grep text1) file2.txt
```

or in different order:

```
cat file2.txt <(ls -a | grep text1)
```

Comment: That's interesting with _-_. But "standard input" ? Did you mean standard output ? How about stderr ?

Comment: @Kenny `-` denotes standard input for `cat`. `info cat` states clearly "‘cat’ copies each FILE (‘-’ means standard input), or standard input if
none are given, to standard output."

Comment: But result of grep text1 would be in stdout, no ?

Comment: @Kenny yes the result of grep will be in stdout of grep, but it is connected to stdin of cat via pipe. BTW, the overall output will be in standard output, a terminal by default. You can redirect it to a file (if you want) normally, i.e. by adding `>file` to the end of the command line.

Answer (score 7):

You can group commands together with `{}` or `()` and redirect their combined outputs:

```
{ 
  cat file1.txt
  echo "Now the ls/grep"
  ls -a |grep foobar
} > file2.txt
```

As a oneliner:

```
{ cat file1.txt; echo "Now the ls/grep"; ls -a |grep foobar; } >file2.txt
```

That last `;` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can just append it on to the end of `file2.txt` by doing

```
ls -a | grep text1 >> file2.txt
```

Or if you want it in a different file

```
ls -a | grep text1 > output.txt
cat file2.txt >> output.txt
```

If you want the stderr instead of stdout

```
ls -a | grep text1 2>> output.txt
```

Note that this probably won't put anything in your file since `ls -a` is unlikely to output anything to stderr.

EDIT: If you want to pipe the results to another program instead of redirecting to a file you'll probably want to use named pipes.

```
mkfifo pipe1
cat pipe1 | next program &
ls -a | grep text1 >> pipe1
cat file2.txt >> pipe1
```

Comment: First solution does not work as asked. It appends to `file2.txt` thus changing it.

Comment: I look for something similar to your second proposition, using cat, but without the need of another file to hold result of the first grep. Imagine if I want to pipe the overall result into something else.

Comment: @Marco They asked to concatenate the files, they never specified where the output should go.

Comment: @Kenny See my edit

Comment: @david-king Look at the end of the first line: `into a final file`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

`ls -a | grep text1 >> file2.txt  2>&1`

`2>&1` will redirect standard err to std output

Comment: it's not a god idea to use redirection in this kind of use

Answer (score 0):

```sh
ls -a | { grep text1; cat file2.txt; } >outfile
```

Here `ls` writes to `grep` which writes to a stdout it shares with the `cat` process that launches when its through filtering `ls`'s output. When `grep`'s `cat` writes a copy of *`file2.txt`* to the same shared stdout. Fewer pipes this way, usually.

... or ...

```sh
ls -a | sed -ne'$r file2.txt' -e'/text1/p' >outfile
```

Here `sed` stands in for `grep` and filters the input to output by printing only matches for a *`text1`* regexp. When it reaches the `$` last of `ls`'s output, it schedules a `r`ead of `file2.txt` to output to occur after it has completely finished the current line cycle - and so as soon as it prints *(or doesn't print)* the last line of `ls`'s output, it copies all of `file2.txt` to its stdout as well.